# tweepy callback_url setting does not work

Tags: django, google-app-engine, twitter, tweepy

The documentation says:

If you have a web application and are using a callback URL that needs to be supplied dynamically you would pass it in like so:

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret,
callback_url)

If the callback URL will not be changing, it is best to just configure it statically on twitter.com when setting up your application’s profile.

I set

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret,
'http://127.0.0.1:8080')
```

and I remove callback_URL in twitter app setting but i does not work.

I set

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret,)
```

and set callback_URL to http:**127.0.0.1:8080 in twitter app setting, then it works

so....tweepy does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'[http://127.0.0.1:8080](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)' (with the double slash) refers to your localhost. If you send that url to someone else, it will refer to their localhost (point to themselves, not you).

If you're actually answering on port 8080 to the world, find the public ip for your host and try registering that.